# spring can't find batch initialization db script

Tags: tomcat, spring-batch

I have deployed a spring batch through a war file in tomcat.
I am running the batch using ContextListener at server start.

Batch launches fine but during database initialization db script is not running.
The script is inside a jar file in WEB-INF/lib folder.
Here is code part from config xml -

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
 <jdbc:script location="jar:file:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql" />
<jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql" />
  </jdbc:initialize-database>
```

it gives me below exception -

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource
>   [/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql]
>           at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
>           at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getReader(EncodedResource.java:132)
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.readScript(ScriptUtils.java:278)
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:438)
>           ... 32 more

Comment: missing code part - <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
 <jdbc:script location="jar:file:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql" />
<jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql" />
  </jdbc:initialize-database>

Answer (score 7):

Note that you are specifying the locations of the two scripts in two different ways: one beginning with `jar:file:org/springframework/...` and the other directly: `org/springframework/...`

Perhaps when you made the changes that others have suggested, you made them only to one of the locations?

But anyways, I was facing the same issue. Adding `classpath:` as the prefix fixed it for me. I'm using Java config to inject the script locations. Earlier it was (the "not working case"):

```
@Value("org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-postgresql.sql")
private Resource dropRepositoryTables;

@Value("org/springframework/batch/core/schema-postgresql.sql")
private Resource dataRepositorySchema;
```

But on changing to the following, it worked:

```
@Value("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-postgresql.sql")
private Resource dropRepositoryTables;

@Value("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-postgresql.sql")
private Resource dataRepositorySchema;
```

The values were then used like this:

```
@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(DataSource dataSource) throws MalformedURLException {

    ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    databasePopulator.addScript(dropRepositoryTables);
    databasePopulator.addScript(dataRepositorySchema);
    databasePopulator.setIgnoreFailedDrops(false);

    DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    initializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator);

    return initializer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this:

```
<jdbc:script location="jar:file:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql" />
```

Should be this:

```
<jdbc:script location="classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this lines. These are working fine in my case:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql"/>
    <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Comment: Not working for me. Have you deployed it as war on tomcat ? how are you  running your batch ? through servlet or context listner ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-oracle10g.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle10g.sql" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database>
```

I am using maven as build tool and deploying on tomcat.